# Copy to range specified by variable reference

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a range to different part of the sheet that can differ in a column used. I recently introduced the variable copy_col to the code that tries to make the destination area flexible and I am using it as a part of R1C1 reference as below. Yet I am receiving 1004 error when running the code. Can anyone help with what I have wrong please?

```
Range("C" & cell2_row + 1 & ":E" & cell_row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("SQL_Structure").Range(Cells(5, copy_col))
```

Comment: Drop the `Range`. You just need `Cells(5, copy_col)`.

Comment: None of that btw are RC reference.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot, works

Comment: That's ok. Eg see this https://bettersolutions.com/excel/formulas/cell-references-a1-r1c1-notation.htm